# Why we need the measure of noncompactness

Tags: measure-theory, operator-theory

I just start studying the measure of noncompactness and I get confused.
Why we try to measure the noncompactness of an operator?
Is it to see if we can obtain a weak noncompactness?!

Comment: I found it interesting to read the references in the Wikipedia article for 'measure of noncompactness'. See for example (https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEYQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.ubbcluj.ro%2F~nodeacj%2Fdownload.php%3Ff%3D052appell.pdf&ei=BnP2UeSXHYP7qAGow4GgCw&usg=AFQjCNEit9Ts2QkpmpCk_ZUr-4i-vNLT8A&sig2=ipzUB6kRAHRDguFDEx7kfw&bvm=bv.49784469,d.aWM) They mention several applications there.

Comment: I had already read that survey and how they gave a generalisation for Schauder and Banach theorems and get from compact to condensing operators, was these generalisations gived by the measure of noncompactness

Answer (score 0):

The compactness is very important and assuming a set to be compact (specially in infinite dimensional spaces) means that we this set behaves like a set of finite dimension. It is clear that this condition is very strong. Many searchers worked on devoloping tools that can replace or weaken the compactness.
One of these tools is the measure of noncompactness which helps us to come over the lack of compactness.